# TestCafe "fixture is not defined" error when importing fixture and tests from multiple files into main.js file

Tags: typescript, testing, automation, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am unable to import tests and a fixture into one main.ts file to run all my tests at once. For organization purposes, I have my tests organized into separate folders. I am getting the error:

```
ERROR Cannot prepare tests due to an error.
ReferenceError: fixture is not defined
```

I've created a main.ts file to run all my tests. I import Fixture(), Test1() and Test2().

main.ts

```
import { Fixture } from "../utils/envUtils";
import { Test1 } from "./testSet1/test1";
import { Test2 } from "./testSet2/test2";

Fixture();
Test1();
Test2();
```

Fixture.ts

```
export const Fixture = () => {
    fixture("Running tests")
}
```

Test1.ts

```
export function Test1() {
    test("Test1", async (t: TestController) => {
         ...
    }
}
```

Test2.ts

```
export function Test2() {
    test("Test2", async (t: TestController) => {
         ...
    }
}
```

If I manually copy and paste the Test1() and Test2() code into the main.ts file, it works. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone else is running into this problem, the solution is to add the `eslint-plugin-testcafe` module to your eslint config.

This is referenced in the TestCafe docs here: https://testcafe.io/documentation/402831/guides/basic-guides/organize-tests like this:

```
Note
If you use eslint in your project, install the TestCafe plugin to
avoid the 'fixture' is not defined and 'test' is not
defined errors.
```

`yarn add -D eslint-plugin-testcafe`
and update your `.eslintrc.json` with the following settings:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "testcafe"
  ],
  "extends": "plugin:testcafe/recommended"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your 'Fixture' import statement does not look correct. Your 'test' functions are incomplete, they miss closing braces. You also need to [install TestCafe locally](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/concepts/typescript-and-coffeescript.html#write-tests-with-typescript) to your test project.

After you fix these issues, test cases will run correctly:

[image]

I attached a complete fixed copy of your tests - this copy runs properly: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pgwp73kf46xuuzm/TypeScriptExample.zip?dl=0